Spring Boot + Thymeleaf dynamic form & list of object
I'm trying to create a form with an unknown number of links for example. Initially, there's 1 input for the link with a button to add another input and again and again.
HTML view
<div class="mb-3">
    <label for="image1" class="form-label">Image</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="image1" placeholder="url" th:field="*{urls}" name="image1" />
    <button id="btn"></button>
</div>

I can easily create other input with Jquery and HTML. But how the value will be send to my controller ?
For now, I did create a specify class to store the urls in List<String> instead of List<Image>.
Is it possible to store directly in images[x].url ?

There are lots of answers about this... have you read this? https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#dynamic-fields

It may work, I haven't got the time to try it out yet. I did temporally put a lot a hidden put and display it when needed. I will look into it this week-end

So, after spending time trying to understand it. It kind of look like that the page is refresh between the add/remove which is fine in the case of a table to display but I have a create form and losing data between each refresh. It doesn't look good but thanks for the answer.
